# How to cancel page activation programmatically?

Tags: java, event-handling, aem

I would like to cancel the activation of some page, when `x!=y` is met. I am trying to do this with `EventHandler`. The author clicks on `activate Page` in the `sidekick`, and my `EventHandler` gets a replication event and tests if `x!=y`. If this is met, the page activation has to be canceled. My question is how do I cancel the page activation?

```
@Component(immediate = true, label = "TEST")
@Service
@Property(name = "event.topics", value = { ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC })
public class EventHandler implements EventHandler {
    String feedback = "";

    public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
        String x = "foo";
        String y = "baar";
        if (x != y) {
            canclePageActivation();
            feedbackForAuthor = "Page can not be activated because x is not equal y";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of page? A web page? Are you using JSP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EventHandler` is invoked *after* page is replicated. What you need here is `com.day.cq.replication.Preprocessor`. If you throw a `ReplicationException` in the `preprocess()` method, replication will be cancelled and user will get the exception message:

```
@Component(metatype = false, immediate = true)
@Service
public class SamplePreprocessor implements Preprocessor {

    @Override
    public void preprocess(ReplicationAction action, ReplicationOptions options) throws ReplicationException {
        if (somethingIsWrong()) {
            throw new ReplicationException("this message will be displayed to the user");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tomek excellent explanation. You are always there to rescue CQ5 guys.