# How to retrieve the selectors from the page URL when a particular page is activated using the side kick. What is the right approach to achieve this?

Tags: aem, sling

I am writing a Preprocessor in AEM. This is a class that runs before a page is activated. When a page is activated I am supposed to activate another page manually using `com.day.cq.replication.Replicator` Service.

But I am heavily dependent on the page's full path including selectors.
My page is http://localhost:4502/content/xxx/americas/US/en/shop/products.12345678.html

In my Preprocessor when I use

```
@Override
    public void preprocess(ReplicationAction replicationAction, ReplicationOptions replicationOptions) throws ReplicationException {
        String payloadPath = replicationAction.getPath();
```

The variable **payload** path holds the value `/content/xxx/americas/US/en/shop/products`

As you can see it does not show the selectors and extension.
How can I get the full path in my Preprocessor. If this were a servlet I would extract the path from SlingHttpRequest. But here the case is different.

I need these selectors and extension as depending on their value my task is to activate other pages.

How do I achieve this in AEM 6.2 ?

I was referring to this questions- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661983/how-to-cancel-page-activation-programmatically)

Comment: The problem is, selectors are only available when a page is requested with them. Within the workflow and replication API you only have access to the resource path and no request data. You also only activate the resource, how do you know what selector is needed?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the info. But you see I really need the selector when the activate page is called. Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: Replication is always associated to a resources whereas selectors are a property for HTTP requests in AEM so you won't be able to access these from preprocess

Comment: @i.net I am willing to change my approach. I won't use Preprocessor. My aim is to activate another page programatically and when a page with multiple selectors is activated.

Comment: In AEM, replication is not associated to selectors and extensions. You always replicate resources. Why does it have to be based on selectors? Remember that a single resource with unique node path can be accessed via multiple extensions and selectors so regardless of your selector(s) you will always end up on the same resource which will be activated. So activating /content/a.sel.html will be same as activating /content/a.sel2.json

Comment: @i.net I understand that but my case is different. The selector is important to me, in my project if a selector is a.sel1.html then I activate a image which has sel1 in its name. In the same way if I have a.sel2.html then I activate all images with sel2 in their name. **So you see it is very very important for me to access the selectors. ON PAGE ACTIVATION**. Kindly suggest me a solution for this problem.

Comment: Ok, can you update your question and detail out on how the page is aware of selector when you hit the publish button? This might hep other members to answer or throw some ideas. Some examples will help. I have a few ideas but need more details so best to expand your question rather than working on comments.

Comment: @Oliver there isn't such a thing as a _page with selectors_. The selector string is a property of an HTTP request that may or may not be a request to render a page. If a user can request the page with different selectors and obtain different images depending on the selctor chosen, you need to activate every image that could potentially be used (for every possible selector), together with the page.